# How to get the earlier hour and the latest hour in each day on a pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a DF that looks like that:

data['date']

```
           date
0   2018-01-01 03:00:00
1   2018-01-01 04:00:00
2   2018-01-01 08:00:00
3   2018-01-02 04:00:00
4   2018-01-02 06:00:00
5   2018-01-02 12:00:00
6   2018-01-03 05:00:00
7   2018-01-03 07:00:00
8   2018-01-03 17:00:00
```

I would like to create to new columns with the earlier and latest hour in each day, something like that:

```
     date_daily     earlier_hour   latest_hour
0   2018-01-01      03:00:00       08:00:00
1   2018-01-02      04:00:00       12:00:00
2   2018-01-03      05:00:00       17:00:00
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) using [`dt.normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) to get the date only as grouper, then [`dt.time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.time.html) for the time component:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])


(df.groupby(df['date'].dt.normalize())
   ['date'].agg(['min', 'max'])
   .apply(lambda s: s.dt.time)
   .reset_index()
 )
```

Output:

```
        date       min       max
0 2018-01-01  03:00:00  08:00:00
1 2018-01-02  04:00:00  12:00:00
2 2018-01-03  05:00:00  17:00:00
```

##### with custom names

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])


(df.groupby(df['date'].dt.normalize().rename('date_daily'))
   .agg(**{'earlier_hour': ('date', 'min'),
           'later_hour': ('date', 'max')})
   .apply(lambda s: s.dt.time)
   .reset_index()
 )
```

Output:

```
  date_daily earlier_hour later_hour
0 2018-01-01     03:00:00   08:00:00
1 2018-01-02     04:00:00   12:00:00
2 2018-01-03     05:00:00   17:00:00
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for your answer. If I wanted to get the second earlier hour, how would I do ?

Comment: If the values are sorted you can use `groupby.nth` or in `agg` use `lambda x: x.iloc[1]` as aggregation function

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with [`GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.apply.html?highlight=groupby%20apply#pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.apply)/[`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) :

```
out = (
    data.groupby(data["date"].dt.date)["date"]
        .agg(["min", "max"]).apply(lambda s: s.dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        .reset_index().set_axis(["date_daily", "earlier_hour", "latest_hour"], axis=1)
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   date_daily earlier_hour latest_hour
0  2018-01-01     03:00:00    08:00:00
1  2018-01-02     04:00:00    12:00:00
2  2018-01-03     05:00:00    17:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the date before grouping to extract the rank of the desired time:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# Use 0 for the earlier hour
# Use 1 for the second earlier hour
# Use -1 for the latest hour
out = (df.sort_values('date').drop_duplicates('date')
         .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D', key='date'))
         .agg(earlier_hour=('date', lambda x: x.iloc[0].time()),
              second_earlier_hour=('date', lambda x: x.iloc[1].time())
              latest_hour=('date', lambda x: x.iloc[-1].time()))
         .reset_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> out
        date earlier_hour second_earlier_hour latest_hour
0 2018-01-01     03:00:00            04:00:00    08:00:00
1 2018-01-02     04:00:00            06:00:00    12:00:00
2 2018-01-03     05:00:00            07:00:00    17:00:00
```